# Jquery Validate with MVC -- Error not updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Am using Jquery Validate plugin in my MVC project.

Code snippet below

```
   UserName: {
                   required: true,
                   remote: {
                      url: "/Test/checkUserName"
                           },
                }
```

And in my TestController

```
public bool checkUserName(string UserName)
            {

                return false;
            }
```

**Required field validation** is working fine.

And for **Remote** my controller is called and false is returned.

But no Error validation is thrown.

Am i doing something wrong  ? What is the correct way to make it work.

Am using Valiadte plugin 1.11.1 and jquery 1.9. Is this something to do with version ?

Comment: Please share your view code also especially the field where remote validation is done.

Comment: @ckv Am not having a Strongly typed view and am performing client side using Jquery validate plugin

Answer (score 0):

Last attribute of ajax is not followed by comma. You have put extra comma after remote{} attribute, remove it.

```
 UserName: {
                   required: true,
                   remote: {
                      url: "/Test/checkUserName"
                           }
                }
```

Comment: No it didnt worked either. False is returned from Controller but nothing happened in Validation

Comment: Does it hits controller method when validation method is called/invoked.

Comment: Yes. and in response am getting false (firebug)

Comment: Trailing commas, although sloppy programming, are only a problem with older versions of Explorer.